# Div Height Issues with Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm new to Bootstrap and am struggling to figure out why my left column height is not displaying as the full height of the parent div. From what I understand in the docs, you just add h-100 as a class to have it take up 100% of the height relative to the parent, but I'm obviously not understanding it right. It probably has something to do with the fact that it's a block element?

```
    <div class="container vh-100">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="row col g-0 d-flex justify-content-center w-75 align-items-center border border-dark">
          <div class="col-6 bg-secondary h-100">
            <h1 class="text-center">Hello There!</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <img src="images/ivy.jpg" alt="ivy" class="img-fluid" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many `row` divs, and a missing `h-100` on the parent...

```
<div class="container vh-100">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="row g-0 d-flex justify-content-center w-75 align-items-center border border-dark h-100">
            <div class="col-6 bg-secondary h-100 border">
                <h1 class="text-center">Hello There!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="images/ivy.jpg" alt="ivy" class="img-fluid" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/RyTy1s0AF8

Note, only columns should be the immediate children of `row`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container vh-100">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="row col g-0 d-flex justify-content-center w-75 align-items-center border border-dark">
          <div class="col-6 bg-secondary vh-100">
            <h1 class="text-center">Hello There!</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/07/21/07/09/cygnet-6482420_960_720.jpg" alt="ivy" class="img-fluid" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Do you mean something like this?

The bg-secondary is now filling the entirety of the div.